# Using log4j2 and JMS appender for auditing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j2

We have a requirement where each log should be sent to active MQ,from there we have a listner which persists this audit data into DB.
Please provide me some direction how to implement this requirement using spring mvc.

Below is the implementation which i could comeup based on the little knowledge i have in log4j2.

I have went thru the log4j2 documentation and have implemented a custom log level "audit" using below command.

```
java -cp log4j-core-2.5.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$ExtendedLogger \
    com.mycomp.AuditLogger AUDIT=350 > com/mycomp/AuditLogger.java
```

I have also configured JMS appender as given below, where the queue name will reside in jndi.properties like "queue.logQueue=queuename"

```
<Appenders>
    <JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="logQueue"
        factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
        factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory" providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} %L ,%m] </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </JMS>
</Appenders>
```

Now when each time we try to log like log.audit("Some Debug message") a message has to be sent to the queue with Info like Ipaddress,username,userrole,method name and simple debug message.

Sample log below

```
016-04-22 14:32:12 DEBUG DemoServiceImpl 32 [ipAddress=166.32.457.87,username=xx123,userrole=admin] [invoking processDetails()]
016-04-22 14:32:12 DEBUG DemoServiceImpl 42 [ipAddress=166.32.457.87,username=xx123,userrole=admin] [invoking populateDetails()]
```

I am constructing above log message using below piece of code

```
StringBuilder logmessage=new StringBuilder();
logmessage.append("[ipAddress=").append(logInfoDTO.getIpaddress())
    .append(",username=").append(logInfoDTO.getUserName()).append(",userrole")
    .append(logInfoDTO.getUserRole()).append("] [").append("invoking populateDetails()]");            
log.audit(message);
```

I am capturing the general info(Ipaddress,username,userrole) in controllers from httpreq ,httpsession objects and setting it in DTO object and passing this across all the layers(service,data.. ).

But this doesn't look like an efficient way , kindly suggest me a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/eventlogging.html. The way I recommend is to capture all the items you always want to appear in audit events into the ThreadContext in a servlet filter or a Spring request interceptor. Then your "audit" events only need to contain the elements specific to the action taking place.  If you leverage the RFC 5424 layout you can end up with one structured data element that contains the event information and another that contains the common information. Of course, you can also format the records as JSON, XML or whatever else you choose.

One side benefit of this is that all your diagnostic events will also have this data attached, so if you are using something like Splunk you would be able to search for events only containing those attributes.

Comment: +10. That reminds me, we're looking at log aggregation at work, so there's some interest in a garbage-free RFC-5424 layout.